# how to set Jenkins pipeline for multiple environment based on different branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to setup jenkins pileline for a repo which have 2 branchs. And I have 2 env on my server

- Master branch - which I want to configure with production env
- Test branch - which I eant to configure with test evn

Please suggest, How should i configure the jenkins pipeline so that it picks up the branch and install then package then deploy.

test branch -> check out -> deploy in test env

master branch -> check out -> deploy in production env

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
    when {
       branch "master"
    }
    steps {
      sh "mvn clean package "
    # configure your prod env 
    }
  }

 stage ('test') {
   when {
     branch "yourtestbranch name"
   }
   steps {
     sh "mvn clean install"
    # configure your test env 
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: if you want to configure stage and it's execution based on branches then this will defenitely will work